# how can I set my ubuntu for flashing my android phone

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to linux/ubuntu.
I installed ubuntu because I was interested in it true my phone (and in the future of course ubuntu touch).
normally I flashed my phone (sony xperia) via flashboot and fastboot.
now I want to get my pc in order to flash again, the only problem is I don't know how to setup-install everything.
of course I googled, because i'm not familiar with ubuntu.

I think I need:

- flashtool
- fastboot
- and (drivers?)
- how do I get it working?
- do I need to obtain su rights? and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can not flash it to a android phone but you can emulate it with Limbo PC emulator.
It is available in play store.

OR

If you want to install ubuntu touch on your device then

follow this link:http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2219740
Only 2011 Xperia models like Xperia Arc are supported and please specify the name of the device.